# Formatting values in class modules

Tags: excel, vba, class

i have the following code

```
Dim W As New WordC ' being WordC the name of my clase
W.Revenue=101545
```

i want to format it as currency but i want it to be done in the class module. how can i do that using properties?

i want something like this code somewhere in the class module

```
If Revenue > 1000000 Then
    Revenue = Format(Revenue / 1000000, "Currency") & "M"
Else
    Revenue = Format(Revenue / 1000, "Currency") & "k"
End If
```

the formatted revenue will only be needed in the class module

Comment: Do you want to store it as currency or as a string? It would seems if you want to store it as currency then simply do so. But in the property to get the information you would translate it to a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Property Let` and `Property Get` to do that:

Clas code 1: this keeps the `revenue` as an integer, and formats it only when you get it with `W.RevenueAsString`.

```
Dim revenue As Integer

Property Get RevenueAsString() As String
    If revenue > 1000000 Then
        RevenueAsString = Format(revenue / 1000000, "Currency") & "M"
    Else
        RevenueAsString = Format(revenue / 1000, "Currency") & "k"
    End If

    Return
End Property
```

Or you can set it as a string instead:

```
Private RevenueInternal As String

Property Get Revenue() As String

    Revenue = RevenueInternal
    Return
End Property


Property Let Revenue(value As Integer)
    If value > 1000000 Then
        RevenueInternal = Format(value / 1000000, "Currency") & "M"
    Else
        RevenueInternal = Format(value / 1000, "Currency") & "k"
    End If
End Property
```

I prefer the first option, since you still have the original value stored as integer in the `revenue` variable. Then you can either work with the actual value with `W.revenue` or with the formatted value with `W.RevenueAsString`.